# Cannot figure out how to set starting values for UIPickerView

Tags: ios

I'm using a `UIPickerView` and would like the section to be the same, the last time it was used.  I looked at Apple's documents on it but did not see anything about setting the sections.

my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // Initialize Data
    _pickerData = @[@"I", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9"];

    // Connect data
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
- (IBAction)aOk:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // store data
    int i=0;
    i=[picker selectedRowInComponent:1]*10;
    i+=[picker selectedRowInComponent:1];
}
- (IBAction)aCancel:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}




// The number of columns of data
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // compment contains the col number
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData[row];
}

// Catpure the picker view selection
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I had the same problem while developing my Trivia Game.  Here's how I solved the issue.

After you've loaded your data, use this select a row:

```
UIPickerView * pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[pickerView setDelegate:self];
[pickerView setDataSource:self];
[view addSubview:pickerView];

//We're going to select a row with this line
[pickerView selectRow:[_pickerData objectAtIndex:0] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

I see you said that you would like the pickerView to default to the last selected row (I think that's what you're trying to say)?

If that's the case, I would just store the last selected row in NSUserDefaults (which is persisted even if the user kills the app).

Whenever the user navigates to the picker view, you can do something like this:

```
NSInteger lastSelectedRow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"lastSelectedRow"];
if (lastSelectedRow)
    [pickerView selectRow:lastSelectedRow inComponent:0 animated:YES];
else
    [pickerView selectRow:[_pickerData objectAtIndex:0] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I cannot get it to work, just stays at the starting postion code

Comment: Put a break point on the if statement ... i.e if (lastSelectedRow).

Does the lastSelectedRow variable have the index you're looking for?  Also, did you store the last chosen index?